# Using old same-version ISO for new install. Any problems?

Tags: iso, system-installation

I have downloaded the Ubuntu 13.10 iso several weeks ago, but hadn't got a time to install the OS, so should it be okay if I burn the ISO to my USB using that ISO, or I should redownload? Will there any new updates being rolled onto me, or they will be updated straight at install? Thanks. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use that ISO.

After installation you will be prompted to update the system and this update will be a bit longer than usual (since it will update everything that was changed since you downloaded it).